# How many items did she want?

Tags: interpretation

[Source](http://thevintagetraveler.wordpress.com/2013/10/28/buttons/#comment-11167)
**I mentioned last week that I still have my grandmother’s button box.  When she sold her house and dispersed her belongings it was one of the two things I wanted most. (Along with her sewing machine, which I foolishly let a cousin take to save a nasty scene.  But that’s another story.)**

I think three.
This button box, the second thing, which is not identified here, and finally this sewing machine.
Am I correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would actually interpret this as *just two-*  the button box and the sewing machine, and since she let the sewing machine go to avoid a scene, she is left with only the button box.

Comment: But "along with" means "in addition to" so the sewing machine is a seprate thing I think.

Comment: I think in this case it means "in addition to the button box"

Answer (score 2):

Decoding the paragraph:

**Sentence 1:** Clearly states that she has the Button box.

**Sentence 2:** Button box and the *'other thing'* she wanted. So 2 things she wanted.

**Sentence 3:** Along with sewing machine => sewing machine is one of the two things she wanted.
This sentence came as an explanation to what the *'other thing'* in sentence2 is.

**So the Result is 2. Two things she wanted.**

The confusing point for you i think is the punctuation between s2 and s3. If it is not there it will be simple in meaning.

Comment: remind that in sentence 2 **the subject is "button box"** which is **"one of the two things"** she wanted most.. and in sentence 3 comes the explanation for **"other thing"** than the button box..

Comment: @BerkerYüceer: That is what I explained.

Comment: What I meant in sentence 2 if you also tell which is the subject would be better to understand and yea my explanation repeats yours. Sorry for that.